# Using for loop to plot subplots

Tags: python

I want to plot 10 revenue trending line chart with date as X axis and show them in a (1,10) compact subplot for easy comparison. Currently I'm getting 10 individual plots separately and it makes comparison difficult.

I've tried subplot within the for loop but it doesn't seem to work.
My data frame shape is as below and I have 10 regions in total.

date | region | revenue

```
region =['a','b','c'...]
for i in region:
  df = df[df['region']==i]
  plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4))
  ax= sns.lineplot(x="date", y="revenue", data=df)
  ax.set_title("region : {}".format(i))
  plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you haven't created any subplots, only a figure:

```
# create figure and subplots
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=10, figsize=(6, 40))

region =['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']

for idx, i in enumerate(region):
  df = df.loc[df['region']==i, :]
  sns.lineplot(x="date", y="revenue", data=df, ax=axs[idx])
  axs[idx].set_title(f"region : {i}")
plt.show()
```

Here we first create a figure with 10 subplots. Then we enumerate the list of regions to get both the region name and its index in the list. Then we plot it just like you did before. Note, that seaborn `lineplot` is an axes-level function and it has `ax` parameter so here we provide it the specific subplot we want to plot on (by its index value).

Answer (score 1):

## Single vs. Multiple plots

It's not entirely clear what is meant by *plotting subplots in a for loop*, so let's see two cases.

#### Single plot with all revenue data for each region

Data pivoting can help to draw all revenue by region in a single plot:

```
df.set_index(['date','region']).unstack('region').plot()
```

or

```
sns.lineplot(pd.pivot(df, columns='region', index='date', values='revenue'))
```

Example:

```
# mock data
regions = [*'ABCD']
my_year = pd.date_range('2022', '2023', freq='M').to_series()
date_range = pd.concat([my_year for _ in regions])
values = np.random.randint(10, 100, size=len(regions)*len(my_year))

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': date_range,
    'region': np.asarray(regions).repeat(len(my_year)), 
    'revenue': values
})

# plotting revenue by region
sns.lineplot(
    pd.pivot(df, columns='region', index='date', values='revenue'),
    ax=plt.figure(figsize=(10, 3.5), tight_layout=True).suptitle('Revenue by region').figure.gca()
)
```

Output:

[image: revenue in a single plot]

#### Separate plots for each revenue by region

With [subplot_mosaic](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot_mosaic.html) we can address each separate axis by a region name:

```
regions = df['region'].unique().reshape(-1, 1)
fig, axes = plt.subplot_mosaic(regions)

for region, group in df.groupby('region'):
    group.plot(x='date', y='revenue', ax=axes[region], title=region)
```

Example:

```
# plot revenue for each region in a separate axis, stack them vertically
height = 1.5
regions = df['region'].unique().reshape(-1, 1)
fig, axes = plt.subplot_mosaic(regions, sharex=True, sharey=True, figsize=(5, height*len(regions)))

for region, group in df.groupby('region'):
    group.plot(x='date', y='revenue', ax=axes[region], legend=None, title=region)

fig.suptitle('Revenue by region')
fig.tight_layout()
```

Output:
[image: revenue by region]

#### How to make the original code work

Single plot:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 4))
ax = plt.gca()

for i in region:
    sns.lineplot(
        x="date", y="revenue", 
        data=df[df['region']==i], 
        label="region : {}".format(i),
        ax=ax
    )

plt.show()
```

Multiple plots:

```
for i in region:
    # df = df[df['region']==i]    because of this line all except the first plot will be empty, so don't do this
    plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4))
    ax = sns.lineplot(x="date", y="revenue", data=df[df['region']==i])
    ax.set_title("region : {}".format(i))
    plt.show()
```